# Shell parameter expansion working in ksh but not in bash

Tags: bash, shell, parameters, ksh, expansion

Why does the following code produce different output in ksh and bash

```
p="folderA/folderB/folderC"
echo ${p%%+([^/])}
echo ${p#${p%%+([^/])}}
```

ksh outputs:

```
folderA/folderB/
folderC
```

bash outputs:

```
folderA/folderB/folderC
```

I'm especially confused because I used the [bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to create this parameter expansion.

I want to extract the folder name after the last slash. I found another way which is working in ksh and bash:

```
echo ${p##*/}
```

but I would like to understand why the first approach is not working.

Comment: What is your bash version? I get proper output on my bash 5.0.11 `the folder name after the last slash` - use `basename` to be most portable. Use `dirname` for the part before the last slash.

Comment: I get one line with bash (4.4.20), zsh, and dash. Two lines with ksh93.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+(...)` is extended glob syntax, you need to enable `extglob` feature for bash to understand it. And as stated in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58305854/10248678), normally a circumflex shouldn't be used for negating a character class. Bash tolerates this mistake, but anyways let's use the correct syntax for the sake of portability:

```
shopt -s extglob
p="folderA/folderB/folderC"
echo "${p%%+([!/])}"
echo "${p#${p%%+([!/])}}"
```

yields:

```
folderA/folderB/
folderC
```

Related link: [Bash Reference Manual § Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching).

---

And btw, you don't really need extended globs for this.

```
p="folderA/folderB/folderC"
echo "${p%${p##*/}}"
echo "${p##*/}"
```

Above script works just as well on any POSIX-compliant shell.

Answer (score 1):

Another, more standards-compliant, Korn shell actually outputs

```
folderA/folderB/folderC
```

followed by an empty line. This is because shell globs are *not* regular expressions, and the character class negotiation operator is a false friend.

In POSIX shell, `[^/]` [is actually unspecified](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_01) but normally (`["^"/]` is more clear) means “either `^` or `/`” but you will want “anything that’s not `/`” which, in POSIX shell globs, is `[!/]` instead.

See [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58285034/2171120) for an explanation on how GNU bash needs `shopt -s extglob` to support Korn shell-compatible extended globbing patterns in addition.